# IE8 .click() gets terminated before request is completed , works on chrome and FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I have a working function that submits a searchString on submit. It works well on FF and Chrome. And when i click the search button it works on all browsers. The problem lies when i call the .click function on enter key hit. It works on FF and Chrome but not on IE8. Didnt test with 9 but i assume it works as well.

```
<input type="text" id="searchString" ><button id="SearchButton" type="submit" onclick="return false;">Look it up!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#SearchButton").click(function() {

    var str = $("#searchString").val();
    if(str.replace(/\s/g,"") == ""){
        $('#loading').hide();
        return false;
    }

 $("#lookupresults").jqGrid('GridUnload');

    $("#lookupresults").jqGrid({
        ... <jqgrid code here>
    });
    ...

});


//this is what detects when i press the enter key , then i call the click of searchbuttong here
$("#searchString").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#SearchButton").click();
    }
});
```

What i get on my logs is:

> HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Connection
>   reset by peer: socket write error; nested exception is
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

this is only on ie8 , when i hit enter on FF and chrome it works fine. also when i hit the look it up! button on ie8 it works fine as well. Is it because of how i call the click() function.

What is the proper way that IE8 will do it properly?

TIA

Comment: Can you put it in a JSFIDDLE page for test?

Comment: you should be returning false from that enter keyup, otherwise it will submit the form regardless of the result of the click event. It would be better to scrap the keyup and click events entirely and use submit event instead.

Comment: What log is that? Can you try debugging in IE8? Hit F12, select the Script tab, and click Start Debugging. That will give you better insight into the issue.

Comment: i figure it is submitting somewhere and the jqgrid load is not being triggered somehow. i tried the even.preventDefault() but it is still giving the same error and not going through the right method when i debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *"proper"* way to do it would be to use the submit event.

```
$("#theform").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var str = $("#searchString").val();
    if(str.replace(/\s/g,"") == ""){
        $('#loading').hide(); // what shows the loader?
        return;
    }
    $("#lookupresults").jqGrid('GridUnload');

    $("#lookupresults").jqGrid({
        ... <jqgrid code here>
    });
    ...
});
```

If you later wanted to cause the form to postback, use this:

```
$("#theform").get(0).submit();
```

Since pressing enter on an input inside a form will trigger the submit event, you no longer need a keyup event on every input of the form to replicate that default behavior.

Comment: i went for this approach ! thanks. im not sure why i went for the on button in the first place thanks!

Comment: but just curious with the case i mentioned on why it doesnt work on ie8 only

Comment: Most likely it's a timing issue.

Comment: i see thanks ! will be coming on this issue sometime when there are no time constraints :D

Comment: My guess is the submit event is triggered before the keyup event happens, which would explain why an event.preventDefault() doesn't solve it. However, i don't understand how this could possibly work in the other browsers without having the same issue.

Comment: oh and thus explains why it doesn't enter the method since the event hasnt even happened yet and the form submits. so when you hit enter on ie8 it always submits the form?

Comment: If you hit enter on an input in ANY browser it always submits the form. What may be different though is *when* the submit happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#searchString").keyup(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $("#SearchButton").click();
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies !its still putting out the exception.